# how to invoke class form dart library string or file

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

who to invoke class form dart library string or file?

for example

for-load.dart file

```dart
class TestLoad {
  void requestHandler(){
  }
}
```

then main.dart file

```dart
main(){
   //this get load lib
   var lib = currentMirrorSystem().libraries[Uri.parse('dart:core')];
   //who to invoke class form TestLoad or for-load.dart? 
   //like java Class.forName('TestLoad') , nodejs require('for-load')
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 5):

These symbols are the names of the Library, the Class and the constructor for the Class that you want to dynamically invoke

**foo.dart**

```dart
library foo_library;

class Foo {
  String bar;
}
```

**invoke_class.dart**

```dart
library new_instance_test;

import "dart:mirrors";
import "foo.dart";

int main() {
  // These symbols are the names of the Library, the Class and the constructor for the Class that you want to dynamically load
  final Symbol librarySymbol = const Symbol("foo_library");
  final Symbol classSymbol = const Symbol("Foo");
  final Symbol constructorSymbol = const Symbol("");

  MirrorSystem mirrorSystem = currentMirrorSystem();

  // Get LibraryMirror for Library foo_library.
  // It returns an iterator, get the first LibraryMirror
  LibraryMirror libraryMirror = mirrorSystem.findLibrary(librarySymbol).first;

  // Get ClassMirror for Class Foo
  ClassMirror classMirror = libraryMirror.declarations[classSymbol];

  // Get the InstanceMirror using the default constructor
  InstanceMirror testClassInstanceMirror = classMirror.newInstance(constructorSymbol, []);

  //Get the reflectee object from the InstanceMirror
  Foo foo = testClassInstanceMirror.reflectee;

  //Set bar and print it
  foo.bar = "foobar";
  print(foo.bar);
}
```

Comment: This code import "foo.dart";   I do not want import. Who to not import but invoke class

Comment: like nodejs require('for-load')

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no way to use a dart library without using an import. I tried using DeferredLibrary but @lazy doesn't work in the dart vm right now, and when I excluded the import statement the library mirror did not appear in the mirror system.

Comment: You may want to look at isolates. You can load a file that has a main() function in it. It will run the code in the main() function separately from the rest of your running code.

Answer (score 0):

Something that could be quite useful for you, as mentioned in the comments, are isolates. If you want to take a look at them, you should look at this [blogpost](http://blog.sethladd.com/2013/04/dynamically-load-code-with-dart.html) of Seth Ladd.
I'll also dig into that topic and see if I can get things running.